# Selenium Data driven testing in perl

Tags: database, perl, selenium, testing, data-driven-tests

Need help on how to do data driven testing using *Excel* & by connecting to *Database*.

Also not able to use Test harness:

```
Can't locate Test/TAP/HTMLMatrix.pm in @INC (@INC contains: D:\Test-WWW-Selenium-1.35\Test-WWW-Selenium-1.35\lib C:/Perl/site/lib C:/Perl/lib .) at Reporttest.pl line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Reporttest.pl line 7.
```

Comment: Details. Don't skimp out on them. Where's your current code? How are you doing this at the moment? What fails? When? How? Duplicated on another machine? What versions of everything are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Selenium not directly supports the Data Driven testing. In simply we can say it use to make interaction with the browser. We can achieve the Data driven using the testing frameworks like `TestNg, Junit etc...`. Otherwise we can do it by any of the programming languages.

I am using testing framework TestNG to retrieve the data from `Excel` and used the java code to retrieve the data from `DB`.

click this [link](http://diveintotesting.com/2013/02/23/parameterizing-selenium-webdriver-tests-using-testng-a-data-driven-approach/) for excel data driven.

Just Google you will get many forums and blogs regarding this question.

Comment: Ya right but im trying it in perl which has plugin TAP formatter, TAP HTMLMATRIX etc to display report in HTML format.
Hence i am getting this error "Can't locate Test/TAP/HTMLMatrix.pm in @INC ".

Comment: Your question is how to do a data driven testing in selenium. You post the above comment as a separate question. You may get the answers.